# ASP.NET_SESSIONID COOKIE not able to prefix with __Host-

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies, oauth, session-cookies

I am in the process of securing cookies by prefixing __Host-. When i tried to prefix the framework generated cookie ASP.NET_SESSIONID , i am not able to do so. I was able to prefix this cookie with any other name but not __Host-

Test_ASP.NET_SESSIONID = Working

__Host-ASP.NET_SESSIONID = Not working

NOTE : THE COOKIE qualifies all the requirements such as

1. came from Https
2. Secure flag set
3. No sub domains . Lies in the root path /.

Appreciate your answers on this. Have been scrathing my head for a month.

Same is happening for 'fedauth' cookie as well.